# Result not refreshed or Click does not work (Selenium + Python)

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to get the result for the [Website](https://www.amfiindia.com/research-information/other-data/mf-scheme-performance-details)

I am not getting any error while clicking on Go button but the result also does not get refreshed. Can any one please help in this.
I tried few ways to click on Go but not working:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="col-sm-1 text-right"]/button[@class="btn btn-primary amfi-btn"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[. = "Go"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@class='btn btn-primary amfi-btn']").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[class="btn btn-primary amfi-btn"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[normalize-space()="Go"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[. = "Go"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//button[@class='btn btn-primary amfi-btn' and @type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: Seems like a functional issue, did you try manually? If yes, was it working ?

Comment: @cruisepandey It is working manually but when running using selenium and clicking on Go button manually as well as via code its not working. Apart from that button everything is working